# Odoo 8 scheduled actions in specific website of Magento Module?

Tags: magento, automation, odoo, magento-1.9, odoo-8

With Odoo I would like to be able to schedule a action to update the stock quantities from Odoo on Magento every day. In my Odoo I have integrated two different magento sites, so each time I plan this action, I update all the quantities of both sites. I would like to be able to update the quantities of a single magento site and not all of them with the planned action.

How can I do?

P.S. I have seen that in the object field is the name of the module "magento.backend". Is it possible to specify the path to the desired website or is it a mistake?

Thank you for every help

Answer (score 0):

If you will have multiple Magento instance and you want to export stock of product instance wise.
You can create Magento instance wise scheduled job for export stock and in job you need to set Arguments as following :

`[[('id','=',<ID of Magento.backend>)]]`

for each Magento instance (Magento Backend)

It will export stock instance wise not Magento website wise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one question, so in arguments of the scheduled actions my code will have to copy and paste it like this for example: [[('id','=',1)]] Right? Thank you.